# Does the preparation of magic states need magic gates?

Tags: magic-states, state-distillation

It is well known that universal quantum computation needs magic states. So we need to prepare magic states although it is noisy. My question is does the preparation of magic states needs magic gates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of universal quantum computation scheme using magic states can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025).

What is shown there is that if you have access to several copies of noisy magic states, you can purify them into fewer copies of less noisy magic states. This can be repeated to obtain copies of even less noisy magic states, and so on until they are accurate enough to be used in the computation (e.g. replacing non-Clifford operations needed to achieve universality).

The scheme itself needs only Clifford gates to complete the purification, so no "magic gates" is involved at this stage.

The scheme must be bootstrapped with a (somewhat) large quantity of noisy magic states not too far from the ideal targeted magic state. Getting them might require some noisy "magic gates", for example you could use noisy physical $T$ gates to obtain the magic states required to implement a noiseless $T$ gate.

Answer (score 0):

No. Using the encoding map is just a way to produce stable source of raw magic states. The fidelity of the raw state depends on the quality of your quantum hardware, which can actually be much higher than you expected.

You can refer the recent experimental demonstration in [here (IBM)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-023-06846-3) and [here (USTC)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.131.210603) for more details. They haven't performed the magic distillation yet, but the produced raw state is said to be over the distill threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, preparing a non-Clifford state (a "magic state") requires a non-Clifford gate (a "magic gate"). I've not heard the term "magic gate" before so it's possible that you mean "perfect gate". The gate does not need to be perfect, since the states can be distilled after they are produced.

The purpose of magic states is to escape from the Clifford operations out into the world of universal operations. If you could produce magic states with only Clifford operations, then Clifford operations would already be universal. An easy way to see this is to realize there's only a finite number of $n$-qubit Clifford operations, and that they're closed under composition, but that there's an infinite number of $n$-qubit operations. There's just not enough Cliffords for them to be universal.